# Prove that $Sup(A + B) = Sup(A) + Sup(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, sumset

Earlier on in the book it showed that to prove $a = b$ it is often best to show that $a \leq b$ and that $b \leq a$. This is the way I want to go about the proof. I am sure there is an easier way but I am new to this and I am trying to get a basic grasp on everything before I start class in the fall. Forgive my terrible MathJax.

Question If $A + B := \{a + b | a \in A \land  b \in  B\}$ Where $A \space and \space B$ are non-empty, bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ then $\sup(A+B) = \sup(A)+\sup(B)$

Since both A  and  B are non-empty bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ if follows that both A  and  B have a finite Supremum. Thus $\sup(A)$ and  $\sup(B)$ exist. Obviously $\sup(A) \geq a \space  \space \forall a \in A$ and $\sup(B) \geq b \space \space \forall \space b \in B$. So $\sup(A) + \sup(B) \geq A + B$ Which means $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is an upper bound of $A + B$ and therefore it follows that $\sup(A) + \sup(B) \geq \sup(A + B)$

Likewise since A  and  B are non-empty bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ It follows that the set $A + B := \{a + b| a \in A \land  b \in B\}$ is also a finite bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ Therefore the set $A + B$ has a finite \supremum so $\sup(A + B)$ exists. Since $\sup(A) + \sup(B) \in A + B$. It then directly follows that $\sup(A+B)$ is an upperbound of $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ and then it directly follows that $\sup(A+B) \geq \sup(A) + \sup(B)$

Which completes the proof that $\sup(A) + \sup(B) = \sup(A + B)$.

Comment: It's not always true that $Sup(A) \in A$, so I'm not sure if $Sup(A) + Sup(B) \in A + B$

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of things wrong: first you write $\sup(A) + \sup(B) \ge A+B$, and second claim that $\sup(A) + \sup(B) \in A+B$.

Your approach is on the right track, though. To get the first inequality you select an arbitrary element $c \in A+B$.  Then $c$ may be expressed as $c = a+b$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  Thus
$$c = a + b \le \sup(A) + \sup(B).$$
This means that $\sup(A) + \sup(B)$ is an upper bound of $A+B$, hence
$$\sup(A+B) \le \sup(A) + \sup(B).$$

On the other hand, for any $\epsilon > 0$ you may select numbers $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ with $\sup(A) < a + \epsilon$ and $\sup(B) < b + \epsilon$. This means that
$$\sup(A) + \sup(B) < a + b + 2\epsilon \le \sup(A+B) + 2\epsilon.$$
The fact that this is valid for arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ gives you that
$$\sup(A) + \sup(B) \le \sup(A+B).$$

Comment: Is there anyway around adding $\epsilon$? Why is this necessary?

Comment: Does this follow from a theorem in the book that states that if $x \lt y + \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \gt 0$ iff $x \leq y$?

Comment: Actually $x \le y$ if and only if $x < y + \epsilon$ for *every* $\epsilon > 0$. Here is a way to avoid $\epsilon$ altogether. Let $a \in A$. Let $b \in B$. Then $a+b \le \sup(A+B)$ so that $b \le \sup(A+B) - a$.  Thus $\sup(B) \le \sup(A+B) - a$.  Then $a \le \sup(A+B) - \sup(B)$ so that $\sup(A) \le \sup(A+B) - \sup(B)$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. How does it follow that $\sup B \leq \sup (A+B) - a$. I can't justify this step.

Comment: @LinusDieLinse the idea is that $b \le \sup (A+B) - a$ for *every* $b \in B$. That means the expression on the right is an upper bound of $B$. In particular it is greater than or equal to the least upper bound, which is $\sup B$.