# Following up with a previous question on $\sup(A)+\sup(B) = \sup(A + B)$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, sumset

The question link is here:

[Prove that $Sup(A + B) = Sup(A) + Sup(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288136/prove-that-supa-b-supa-supb/3288145#3288145)

Can someone look at the answer given and explain why epsilon is introduced and how that whole second part works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for $\epsilon$s.

The key idea is that if $x \le u$ for all $x \in X$ then $\sup X \le u$.

Note that if $a \in A, b \in B$ then $a+b \le \sup A + \sup B$ and so
$\sup (A+B) \le \sup A + \sup B$.

Similarly, $a+b \le \sup (A+B) $, so $\sup A + b \le \sup (A+B)$ for all $b$ and hence
$\sup A + \sup B \le \sup (A+B)$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: +1 for simpler approach and I think the downvote is related to the fact it does not deal the $\epsilon$ which asker wants to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Because the definition of $\sup A$ ,for each $\epsilon > 0,\sup A < a+\epsilon.$

Remember **$A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$.**

Comment: Copper.hat ‘s answer is also right and more easier to understand for tyro.